# Unable to PING EC2 instance even after adding ICMP inbound rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ping

Problem definition:- I have two EC2 instances, one in a public subnet and another one in private subnet. Now I am able to RDP from the Public Subnet instance to the private instance but could not ping it even after adding rules like "ICMP". But PING works the other way round i.e. I am able to ping the public instance from the private one. I will try to explain this as below:-

1. I created an EC2 instance in a public subnet, let’s name this EC2 instance as BASTION HOST and I allowed RDP and PING (ICMP) from "all" (internet – 0.0.0.0/0) in the inbound request of the security group (SG1) that’s attached to the EC2. This EC2 is working as expected, for example I can ping or RDP to this instance using its public IP address from internet.
2. Next I created another EC2 instance in private subnet, let’s call it EC2SQL1. I have requirement that I shall be able to ping BASTION to EC2SQL1 and vice versa. But that’s not happening, I can ping to the BASTION from EC2SQL1 but not the other way around even though I added the ICMP, “all traffic” rules (also the RDP rule) in inbound request of the security group (let’s call it SG2 that is associated with EC2SQL1). I have tried keeping SG1 as the source as well as tried with the CIDR range of the VPC. Strange enough that the RDP from the Bastion to EC2SQL1 is working but the ping request fails no matter what rule is added, so does any telnet to TCP ports. So what I am missing here?

(A) My public and private subnets have different route tables that you can see in the picture below.
[image]

(B) Both instances are however using the same NACL:

[image]

(C) The security group rules associated with EC2SQL01 is as below, despite which my TCP, telnet, PING nothing works but RDP works (or telnet to RPD port also works):-

[image]

In my desperation I added so many inbound rules but nothing seems to be working that can allow a ping or telnet to a TCP port from BASTION host to EC2SQL01, and yes I am using Private IP for ping or telnet or RDP from BASTION to EC2SQL01 or vice versa from within the VPC.

(D) Outbound rule of both the security groups looks like below telling that everything is allowed:-

[image]

Any suggestions is much appreciated

Comment: Windows firewall blocks ICMP by default. Any chance that you have allowed ICMP through the bastion's Windows firewall but did not on the SQL host?

Comment: Why do you want to use PING? That would merely demonstrate that PING works. It is normally better to try and get woking the thing that you want working (eg SSH) rather than something else.

Comment: You need `Echo Request`, not `Echo reply`

Comment: Thank you Marcin, I tried with echo request too, but that doesn't work either. I don't have a NAT gateway association in the route table of my private subnet, any chance is that making my life difficult.

Comment: Thank you John, i opened TCP all and UDP all to test telnet to the TCP port from Bastion toEC2SQL1 at which my SQL server is listening but even that is not working. Strange enough that if I tenet to the RDP port 3389, telnet goes thru.

Comment: Thank you Jarmod, I haven't made changes to Windows firewall in either host, but I will take a look.

Comment: Thank you Jarmod, appears you are right, after I opened the ICMP at Windows for my EC2 instances PING command works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

So appears Windows firewall still blocks the traffic whether PING or TCP, what I did is simply turned OFF the EC2 Windows firewall and then it started working as per the RULES defined in our AWS security groups.

If we don't want to turn off the firewall altogether then I had to explicitly ALLOW the ICMP inbound rule for Windows firewall, but then again TCP was not working.

Hope this helps, any difference of opinion please feel free t share. Thanks.